# How do I add the tertiary level from the main menu to my skin?

Tags: 7, routes

Let's say I have the following menu:

- Smartphones

  - Android

    - LG Nexus 4
    - Samsung Galaxy Note 2
    - HTC One
    - Motorola Droid RAZR MAXX HD
  - iOS

    - iPhone 4
    - iPhone 4S
    - iPhone 5
  - Windows Phone

    - HTC Windows Phone 8X
    - HTC Windows Phone 8S
    - Nokia Lumia 920
    - Nokia Lumia 820

I want a menu that will display all the third level items if I'm on the parent node.  So, if I'm on the **Android** page, I should see *LG Nexus 4, Samsung Galaxy Note 2, HTC One, and Motorola Droid RAZR MAXX HD*.

The only recommendation I keep seeing is to use the Menu block module, but I want to just create the menu myself in PHP.  How?

Comment: Have you checked out Cute Menus or Accordion Menus modules?

Comment: @longboardnode No I haven't.  I do not want to use a module.

Comment: ok, can you clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve or a sample menu strucutre of what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  In **template.php**, I added the following function:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $active_tree = menu_get_active_trail();
    $parent = array_pop($active_tree);
    if($parent['depth'] == 3) {
        $parent = array_pop($active_tree);
    }

    $parameters = array(
        'active_trail' => array($parent['plid']),
        'only_active_trail' => FALSE,
        'min_depth' => 3,
        'max_depth' => 3,
        'conditions' => array('plid' => $parent['mlid']),
      );

    $tertiary_menu = menu_build_tree($parent['menu_name'], $parameters);

    $links = array();
    foreach($tertiary_menu as $branch=>$link) {
        array_push($links, $link['link']);
    }

    $tertiary_links_vars = array(
        'links' => $links,
        'attributes' => array('class' => array('sub-nav')),
        'heading' => array(
            'text' => t('Tertiary menu'),
            'level' => 'h2',
            'class' => array('element-invisible'),
        ),
    );

    $variables['tertiary_menu'] = theme_links($tertiary_links_vars);
}
```

In my **page.tpl.php** file, I added the following:

`<?php print $tertiary_menu; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

I follow cowgod in his solution, although I propose a slight tweak which allows a more flexibel rendering of the menu in the template:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $active_tree = menu_get_active_trail();
    $parent = array_pop($active_tree);
    if($parent['depth'] == 3) {
        $parent = array_pop($active_tree);
    }

    $parameters = array(
        'active_trail' => array($parent['plid']),
        'only_active_trail' => FALSE,
        'min_depth' => 3,
        'max_depth' => 3,
        'conditions' => array('plid' => $parent['mlid']),
      );

    $tertiary_menu = menu_build_tree($parent['menu_name'], $parameters);

    $links = array();
    foreach($tertiary_menu as $branch=>$link) {
        array_push($links, $link['link']);
    }

    $variables['tertiary_menu'] = $links;
}
```

In **page.tpl.php** , you can then add:

```
<?php 
    print theme('links', array(
      'links' => $tertiary_menu,
      'attributes' => array('class' => array('sub-nav')),
      'heading' => array(
        'text' => t('Tertiary menu'),
        'level' => 'h2',
        'class' => array('element-invisible'),
      ),
    ); 
?>
```

This way, you'll have a more flexible solution.

Comment: Hi Nils and welcome. This website has a Q&A model, not a traditional forum. There is only one good answer, not a thread of suggestions. Please update your answer to include all the details so it becomes a complete answer to the question.